# Django app in deployment cannot find .css or .js files even though I ran collecstatic?

Tags: python-3.x, django, nginx

It has been a while since I touched this but finally getting back into working on this gargantuan website (mostly static pages thus far).  I have it running great locally but on deployment... well not so much. It gives errors it cannot find .css and .js files that are clearly there (in both the static and where the collecstatic puts things).

This is a **linux** deployment using **gunicorn** and **nginx**, I even restarted gunicorn (actually that borked up so I ended up restarting the whole box).

Key part of the settings.py is:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static")
```

Lastly, this was working, I just did a git pull, `python3 manage.py collecstatic` and bam all the new look and feel stuff is like it is not there.  Not sure what else to do or check.  Guessing it is a simple fix just not sure what I am doing.

Also again things were working, just my latest git pull which was all cosmetic stuff (a new menu etc, which means new css/js and a few new pngs) are all not found now?   Even though see they are there.

Django version is: 3.2.1

Collect static output:

```
(apo_web) [root@newapo django_apo]# python3 manage.py collectstatic
base dir: /home/workers/apo_web/django_apo

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    /home/workers/apo_web/static

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Found another file with the destination path 'css/style.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
Found another file with the destination path 'fonts/FontAwesome.otf'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
Found another file with the destination path 'fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
Found another file with the destination path 'fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
Found another file with the destination path 'fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
Found another file with the destination path 'fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
Found another file with the destination path 'fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.

1 static file copied to '/home/workers/apo_web/static', 917 unmodified.
```

The one file copied was a png I edited just to test. So it means the other files were copied correctly to /home/workers/apo_web/static and the ones are there.

Nginx config (the relevant parts I think)

```
   server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

Sites-enabled conf file under /etc/nginx/sites-enabled:

```
  server {
            listen 8080;
            server_name 10.75.1.214;

            location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
            location /static/ {
                root /home/workers/apo_web/django_apo;
            }

            location /media/ {
                # root /media/;
                alias /media/;
           }

             location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/run/apo_web.sock;
                }
    }
```

And a git pull indicated I updated my project with really just cosmetic changes, new code in html templates, new css files and js files and more html files than before.  The new css files and js files got pulled, and placed in the project static and later in the proper static with a collectstatic which is why I cannot figure out why the webpage is still complaining under chome/development tab that it cannot find file x.y.z.css or x.y.z.png or x.y.z.js
etc

Comment: Try using whitenoise, it helped me. https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ check the documentation here

Comment: `It gives errors` show full error messages. `nginx` show nginx config part related to serving static files. `python3 manage.py collecstatic` show this command output. The question lacks details, nothing to deal with. `i did git pull` does not elaborate anything.

Comment: Maybe your static files are in a directory that you have not set in django?
``STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
)``
Here I'm telling Django to search the static files in the assets directory

Comment: @JonathanArleyMonsalveSalaza I would agree but the directory I told django they are indeed there.  This is why I am confused, I will double check all settings make sure I didn't clobber something in the settings.py but I didn't change anything just switched up my html to use a new css file it now cannot find when deployed.  Even though the old css file it finds just fine.

Comment: `/home/workers/apo_web/django_apo/static` != `/home/workers/apo_web/static` nginx root for `/static/` does not match `STATIC_ROOT` where collectstatic delivers files.

Comment: Stupid me, that was a great find ty! all is well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what i see your static root folder is not in the right directory, remove the old static directory and run `python manage.py collectstatic` and now reconfigure the new static folder path in your nginx conf file at

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/<your_nginx_server_file>
```

e.g if your static directory was created at at project's base directory

> /home/workers/apo_web/django_apo/static
> then in nginx server block it should be like

```
location /static/ {
        root /home/workers/apo_web/django_apo;
    }
```

now run `sudo nginx -t` if no errors found restart nginx and gunicorn

```
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```